# Resize Chart on Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

so my problem is pretty simple to describe but i cant find an answer around here.

So i have created a Chart As worksheet (think you know what i mean), so i havent created a chart on a worksheet but a char as worksheet.

the problem now i have is that i cant change the size of it, but i have so many values that i cant read anything on this chart. I need the chart as worksheet, because i need the events of an chart which are only present if you have it like a worksheet.

I hope someone can help me.

```
Charts.Add2
Chart.Name= "Grafik"
Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = arrAnz
Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = arrTxt
Chart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Häufigkeit der Fehler"
Chart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue
Chart.Activate


'those wont work
Chart.Parent.Height
Chart.ChartArea.Height 'runtime error Form is locked and size cannot be changed
```

Comment: Hello Tom, I don't think it is possible to change the size of a chart sheet. It will always fill up the whole sheet. You could use another paper size, smaller margins and/or zoom in, though.

Comment: how can i change the paper size? maybe that would help, zoom does not help, there are to many values ^^

Comment: Seitenlayout -> Format

Comment: can i somewhere put in my own values for the layout?

Comment: As far as I know, only those paper sizes supported by your printer(s) are available. But I have to say that I do not use this functionality very often, so I am not 100% sure.